# moving control from android application to browser

Tags: android, baseadapter

Actually i am doing a application with facebook feedlike view with listView. And I have a url in the in the feed. When i click that Url I need to go to the browser with that url to search in it. So as i am using `ListView` i should extend BaseAdapter. Can anyone tell me how to transfer control from my app to browser. What should i Use. I tried using

```
browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,    Uri.parse("http://some url"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But it is not working in the class which extends base adapter how can i solve the problem. Thanks in advance.And sorry if the answer is crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the below sample app which has every possible code you can do to connect a website and a android app.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="www.this-so-does-not-exist.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add this in your manifest file below activity which you want to navigate from your website

Comment: The sample u have given extends activity but I need to know how to go from a class which extends BaseAdapter